# How to declare a variable that can not insert in function

Tags: php

I wanna declare a function with 2 Input parameters.

```
function myFunc( $first , $second )
    {
       return $first;
    }
```

When it called I only need the first parameter and don't wanna use "NULL" for the second.

```
echo myFunc("Hello");
```

Sorry because of my poor English

Thanks

Comment: What about `false`? `function myFunc( $first , $second = false )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php's [default arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php). In this example, you can set the second parameter to default to `null` (or any default value that you want), and therefore you will only have to pass one parameter.

```
function myFunc( $first , $second = null )
{
   return $first;
}

echo myFunc("Hello");
```

Comment: This also doesn't appear to be what the OP is after, `don't wanna use "NULL" for the second`. Although it is unclear why or what the OP actually wants.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
function myFunc( $first , $second='whatever' )
{
   return $first;
}
```

You can give anything in place of 'whatever'

Answer (score 0):

you can use default params as only if you do not want use null:

```
function myFunc( $first , $second = 0 )
{
  return $first;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function myFunc( $first , $second=NULL )
{
   return $first;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's the english but this doesn't seem to be what the OP wants. `don't wanna use "NULL" for the second`

Comment: I understood that him does not want to type NULL for the second parameter.
myFunc("hola", NULL)

Comment: You are setting the second parameter to `NULL` though..

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: the best answer is very similar to this -_-